# maximum principle for $p$-Laplace equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider $\Omega \subset R^n$ a bounded domain. Let $\varphi \in W^{1,p}(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Let $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $\Delta_p u = 0$ in $\Omega$ with $u - \varphi\in W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$ . Can I conclude that $u \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Intuitively the answer is "yes" (I believe that exists a comparison principle for the above situation). But I am not finding a reference. Someone could point me a reference?

I am just looking for a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\phi$, let
$$
A=\{u\in W^{1,p};u-\phi\in W^{1,p}_0\}
$$
be the admissible set.
The solution $u$ is the unique minimizer of the Dirichlet energy
$$
I(v)=\int_\Omega|\nabla v|^p
$$
in the set $A$.
(This is a standard result in calculus of variations.)

Now, let $M=\sup\phi$ and $m=\inf\phi$ and define
$$
v(x)
=
\begin{cases}
M, & u(x)>M\\
m, & u(x)<m\\
u(x) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now $v\in W^{1,p}$ and also $v\in A$.
One can check that $|\nabla v|\leq|\nabla u|$ pointwise, so $I(v)\leq I(u)$.
Since $u$ is the unique minimizer of $I$ in $A$, we have $u=v$.
This means that $u$ is bounded from above by $\sup\phi$ and from below by $\inf\phi$.
In particular $u\in L^\infty$.

I suppose you could find the comparison principle for the $p$-Laplace equation in most PDE books that cover the equation.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for your help

Comment: when I read your answer I understand.  But now I am not understanding why $v \in A$. Please could you explain? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @mathstudent, that is a tricky part. I guess you need an approximation argument there. The claim is quite obvious for functions that take their boundary values in the classical sense. Perhaps something like this works in the general case: Approximate $\phi$ by a $C^\infty$ function (in $W^{1,p}$ and $L^\infty$), then approximate $u-\phi$ by a $C^\infty_0$ function. I don't have the time to check this now, though, and probably won't have time before Christmas. There are probably neat solutions available in textbooks and lecture notes on the equation.

Comment: Ok . No problem! Thanks  for all your help and for your attention!

Comment: @mathstudent, use Stampacchia's theorem combined with the fact that $v(x)=\phi(u(x))$, where $\phi$ is a Lipschitz function with $\phi(0)=0$.